# conda throw error and and replace 'conda_~1' instead of table name in ci3

Tags: php, codeigniter, anaconda, conda

ERROR - 2023-08-10 08:03:40 --> Query error: Table 'nutrelab_db.c:\conda_~1' doesn't exist - Invalid query: SELECT 1
FROM `C:\CONDA_~1`

I am trying to run a project and I already installed anaconda and also set up path in global environment but still getting these error also I am trying to remove anaconda from my project but still not changes